# issue with array in shell on ubuntu

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, ubuntu, centos

I used to have a server running CentOS, and I used to execute shell files this way:

```
sudo sh /folder/script.sh
```

Now I have an Ubuntu server. When I'm executing the same command line, I now have the following error message:

```
/folder/script.sh: ID[0]=ID: not found
```

I had a look on the internet and it says I need to use:

```
sudo /bin/bash /folder/script.sh
```

But when I do so I got the same error message.

The first line of my script is:

```
ID[0]="ID"
```

Comment: paste first few lines of your script. You might be missing shebang..

Comment: thanks a lot for having a look @almasshaikh I just edited my message

Comment: add this `#!/bin/bash` as a first line.

Comment: still got the same error @almasshaikh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/bin/sh` is often a POSIX shell, which does not support arrays.

I suggest you install another shell which *does* support them, like [mksh](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mksh) (disclaimer: I’m its developer), [ksh93](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ksh), [zsh](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zsh), or just use GNU [bash](http://packages.ubuntu.com/bash) instead, and call your script with, for example, `sudo mksh /folder/script.sh` instead. This will give you more consistent behaviour across systems, too (note that to behave consistent on all platforms is actually an mksh design goal).

Hm… this works for me:

```
$ cat >x
#!/bin/bash
ID[0]="ID"
echo works for me
$ mksh x
works for me
```

Do you have any weird characters in your script, like embedded Carriage Return (`^M`)? Check with: `cat -v /folder/script.sh`

Comment: i got exactly the same error : "ID[0]=ID: not found"

Comment: Thanks for your help, I used mksh, well actually "ID[0]=ID: not found" is the second line, the first line is #!/bin/bash

Comment: it also works for me, in your example you are not quotting your string, gotta try this way